# PWM motor control PIC18F4550 code

Tags: microcontroller, pic, dc-motor, motor-controller, programmer

I am trying to build a PWM motor controller using a PIC18F4550 and I am new on PIC programming I need help to check and improve my code?

My project details:
I have two analog values from movement system as an error signal.
I need to generate PWM signal due to these values to control the motor.
one signal for CW direction / another for CCW direction.
"There are some calculations to scaling these values but first I need to check if I can control the motor."

I used mikro C compiler and ADC, PWM library.

[image: circuit schematic]

My code:

```
unsigned int adcrd1;
long currentduty1;
unsigned int adcrd2;
long currentduty2;

void main() {
  TRISA.RA2 = 1;
  TRISA.RA3 = 1;
  TRISC = 0;
  TRISB = 0;

  PWM1Init(6000);
  PWM1Start();
  PWM2Init(6000);
  PWM2Start();
  ADC_Init();

  PORTB.F0 = 1;

  while (1) {
    adcrd1 = ADCRead (2);
    adcrd2 = ADCRead (3);
    currentduty1 = (long) adcrd1 * 240;
    currentduty1 = currentduty1 / 1023;
    currentduty2 = (long) adcrd2 * 240;
    currentduty2 = currentduty2 / 1023;

    if (adcrd1 > adcrd2) {
      Delayus(50);
      pwm1setDuty(currentduty1);
      pwm2setDuty(0);
    }
    else if (adcrd2 > adcrd1) {
      Delayus(50);
      pwm2setDuty(currentduty2);
      pwm1setDuty(0);
    }
    else {
      Delayus(100);
      pwm1setDuty(0);
      pwm2set_Duty(0);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: configration1][image: configration2]

Comment: Overall you need to state your expected accuracy/tolerance. Do you really need 32 bit PWM? As for the code, using busy-delays is almost always wrong/bad design, use hardware timers. Also you should replace all types with `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`.

Comment: thank you Lundin. can you explain more about uint16_t and uint32_t  please ?